# Triggering code when LiveData finishes loading?

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-databinding, android-livedata

I have a `spinner` where the items available to be selected and the currently selected item are data-bound to `LiveDatas` in my `ViewModel`. I know the currently selected item before starting the activity (it's passed into the activity) but the available items are fetched from the database. The issue I'm having is when the activity is started (and the activity gets a reference to the ViewModel) the currently selected item is set and this completes before all items can be fetched from the database. This results in my currently selected item being overridden in the spinner.

Spinner

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   app:selectedValue="@={viewmodel.selectedItem}"
   android:entries="@{viewmodel.itemsList}" />
```

ViewModel

```
public class MyViewModel extends ViewModel
{
    // Repository
    private final Repository repository;

    // LiveData
    public LiveData<List<Item>> itemsList;
    public MutableLiveData<Item> selectedItem = new MutableLiveData<>();

    public MyViewModel(Repository repository)
    {
        this.repository = repository;        
        itemsList = repository.getItems();
    }

    public void setSelectedItem(Item item)
    {
        selectedItem.postValue(item);
    }
}
```

Is there a way around this? A potential solution would be to set the selected item later but that seems hackish as it's based on timing.